# "OpenID" request was rejected by "google" as outdated

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-openid, secret-key

I can't post a screenshot (NO REP) but here's the page: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2

The client I'D and Secret Key request now deprecated and instructions to post here with the correct tag.
  Does OpenID affect just these (firebase, cloud console & dev.play console) or others like Azure,  Android's console or
Visualstudio? Or keep it anyways for easy logins?
   Thanks for your time and input.